# Check if user login and password exist on server using WCF RESTful service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm developing a WCF RESTful web service with C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and Entity Framework 4.4.0.0.

On a SQL Server database I have a table with users and I want to check if an user exists on that table sending login and password.

I have this URI: `/users/{user_id}` to **GET** an user using its `UserId`.

I think, I can do this: `/users/login/{login}/password/{password}` but I don't know if this is the right way to do it because login and password are public.

**How can I check if exist an user with the same login and password without showing them on the URI?** (Maybe, `/users/login/{login}/password/{password}`, this is the right way).

**NOTE**: the password is encrypted.

Comment: using username and password in the url?! don't do that! you should use post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a RESTful API then really it should be stateless - which means sending the user/password on each request or a token on each request.

You will need to run the site under SSL for it to be secure. Your user/password or token should be in the header. For a simple site I would recommend using Basic HTTP authentication (google it if you don't know what it is). You base64 encode the username/password and send them with each request. Have a look here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149738/Basic-Authentication-on-a-WCF-REST-Service

One more thing - I may be wrong as I don't know the details of your project but I don't think you need a 'confirm' service. It sounds like you have this for the purposes of logging in. I would suggest that when a user logs in you direct them to your dashboard or landing area. If the user is not authenticated at this point then redirect to login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I made a mistake on my question, and this is what I want to know: `How can I check if exist an user with the same login and password without showing them on the URI?`

Comment: If you use basic HTTP auth you should be able to do this. You will put the username/password in the header rather than the URL

Answer (score 0):

WCF (REST) services are [supposed to be stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680229/stateful-wcf-web-service). Use a different way of authentication. See [User authentication for mobile clients in RESTful WCF 4 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588691/user-authentication-for-mobile-clients-in-restful-wcf-4-service) and [User/Pass Authentication using RESTful WCF & Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395892/user-pass-authentication-using-restful-wcf-windows-forms).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I made a mistake on my question, and this is what I want to know: `How can I check if exist an user with the same login and password without showing them on the URI?`

Comment: Just query `/users/login/{login}`?